# Unir 4 bases de datos en diferentes servidores locales

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Como puedo unir 4 bases de datos sql server para que se comuniquen entre ellas, cada base de datos está configurada en un Servidor local y cada servidor está en un país, dando cuenta el tema del VPN y alguien me pueda ayudar si se puede instalar un Servidor cloud intermediario como Azure para que haga la union.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Después de conectar las 4 bases de datos ¿Qué vas a hacer con ellas? ¿Tienen todas la misma estructura o son completamente distintas? Tu problema es muy ambiguo

Answer (score 1):

Quizás lo que buscas es crear diferentes "Linked Servers" desde un SQL en un servidor que vea a los 4, luego para recoger los datos y unirlos se podría hacer con comandos MERGE desde ese servidor "de unificación". Quizás esto te sirva de ayuda: [SQL MERGE remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236961/sql-merge-to-remote-linked-server-table)